# Select field inside buefy table in vue

Tags: vue.js, buefy

<s>So I have a buefy table set up that is pulling in data from firebase.</s>

```
<b-table :data="users" :columns="columns"></b-table>
```

It all seems to be working fine. In a "normal" table, I could add in a select to my column (to change a user's role) with @click

```
<td data-label="name">{{ user.email }}</td>
<td>
  <b-field label="Select a Role">
    <b-select @change.native="changeRole(user.id, $event)" placeholder="Select Role">
        <option :selected="user.role.driver" value="driver">Driver</option>
        <option :selected="user.role.customer" value="customer">Customer</option>
    </b-select>
  </b-field>
</td>
```

However, I am quite unsure of how to achieve this in the buefy table. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?
In my export default, I currently have

```
data() {
            return {
                users: [],
                user: null,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'id',
                        label: 'ID',
                        width: '40',
                        numeric: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'email',
                        label: 'Email',
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'role',
                        label: 'Role',
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'select',
                        label: 'Select Role', //used for testing/doesnt work
                    },
                ]

            }
        },
```

**Update**

So I switched to vue and got up and running again (nuxt was a bit restrictive in what I actually wanted to accomplish), but am still having a headache with select fields inside of the buefy table. This table resides in the admin view so an admin could change the role of a user.

I stumbled across using the b-table-column & props and thought I was going to be able to achieve what I want. However, for the life of me I cant see how to do this.

My table:

```
            <b-table :data="isEmpty ? [] : users">
                <template slot-scope="props">

                    <b-table-column field="email" label="User Email">
                        {{ props.row.email }}
                    </b-table-column>

                    <b-table-column field="role" label="Access Level">
                        select field goes here

                    </b-table-column>


                </template>
            </b-table>
```

I have a firebase collection (roles) that I am associating with the registered users by uid which works great so I get back:

```
    userid: "uniqueid"
    email: "test@email.com"
    role: (basic: true)
```

Now I need to pass this data into a select field so I can edit the user's role with an @change in vue ie:

```
<select @change="changeRole(user.id, $event)">
   <option :selected="user.role.basic" value="basic">Basic</option>
   <option :selected="user.role.gold" value="gold">Gold</option>
   <option :selected="user.role.diamond" value="Diamond">Diamond</option>
</select>
```

In my js, I currently have the following which is pushing the role into the specific user.

```
this.users = [];
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("roles")
            .get()
            .then(snap => {
                snap.forEach(doc => {
                    var user = doc.data();
                    user.id = doc.id;
                    console.log(doc.data());
                    if (!user.role.admin) this.users.push(user);
                });
```

Im not really sure if this is even possible, but if anyone has any thoughts at all I would appreciate it.